# Svn diff command - ignoring of specific lines

Tags: svn

Is there any way to make svn diff command ignore some specific lines in a source code file, so consider this as not a changes?

Comment: Particular line numbers or particular line contents?  Note that you can use `--diff-cmd` to specify the command used to do the diffing, so you could always write your own diff command.

Comment: Well I think this is the only solution.

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail of what you're trying to do?  Another possibility would be post-processing the output to remove the lines you don't care about (eg `svn diff | grep -v foo`).

Comment: Basically, I need to ignore lines in some specific file with changes located only in expressions like "line=123". This changes are not giving any useful information when I see svn diff output, so I'd like to make svn diff ignore such changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only ignore white spaces. Read the svn manual for more information: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html